# Dynamically loading name of Java class file in a Quartz job

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, classloader

I have a Quartz job written in Java which runs fine if I have the Quartz JobDetail line set as follows:

```
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("FeedMinersJob", scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, FeedMinersScheduler.class);
```

But I would like to dynamically load the class because the job details are stored in a database table. So I want something like this:

```
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail(sj.getJobName(), scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, sj.getJobClassFile());
```

Where sj is a scheduled job object and method sj.getJobClassFile() returns the name of the class defined in sj instead of having the class name hardcoded.

I've tried permutations of the Java Class.forName method but without success.

Comment: What did you try and what problems did you encounter? Compile error? Exception in runtime? No exception but results of execution not satisfying?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.
It does not output anything, and does not throw an error either.
This is because your job class doesn't have an empty constructor. So even though the code is correct, it has no mechanism to create the job object.
If you add an empty constructor to your Job class, itwill work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you code should like this:

```
Class<?> jobClass = Class.forName(sj.getJobClassFile());
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail(sj.getJobName(), scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, jobClass);
```

Can you please post the code snippets which didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try {
    Class<?> jobClass = Class.forName(sj.getJobClassFile());
    JobDetail jd = new JobDetail(sj.getJobName(), scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, jobClass);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // put here some error handling
}
```

And if it doesn't work **please** give more details about the problem - compilation error, exception in runtime or some other problem.

Comment: This is almost precisely what I have except I'm testing for any exception. But there are no compiler warnings or runtime exceptions at all. Simply put, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I have this, maybe it will be usefull to you: (getClassName() returns a string)

```
Class<?> jobClass = Class.forName(t_job.getClassName());
if (Job.class.isAssignableFrom(jobClass)) {
        // create a job detail that is not volatile and is durable (is persistent and exists without trigger)
        JobDetail job = new JobDetail(t_job.getName(), t_job.getGroupName(), jobClass, false, true, true);
        job.setDescription(t_job.getDescription());

}
```